# FindWindow in FM

Tags: delphi, findwindow

I am trying to use findwindow api call in FM, I can use it find in a VCL application, but not FM.

Here is my code

```
    function WindowExists(titlename: string): boolean;
    var
      hwd: THandle;
    begin
      hwd := 0;
      hwd := FindWindow(nil, pchar(titlename));
      Result := False;
      if not(hwd = 0) then { window was found if not nil }
       Result := True;
   end;
```

and here is the error I get when I try to compile
[dcc32 Error] global_proc.pas(62): E2010 Incompatible types: 'HWND' and 'Pointer'

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Completely unrelated to FMX. Problem lies in incoherence in Windows API.with windows handle type and general handle type.

Comment: @Free Hardly. The issue is that the `FindWindow` here is `FMX.Platform.Win.FindWindow`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems likely that your problem is that your code is finding `FMX.Platform.Win.FindWindow` rather than `Winapi.Windows.FindWindow`. Furthermore `FindWindow` returns an `HWND` and not a `THandle`.

Your code should be like this:

```
function WindowExists(const TitleName: string): Boolean;
var
  wnd: HWND;
begin
  wnd := Winapi.Windows.FindWindow(nil, PChar(TitleName));
  Result := wnd <> 0;
end;
```

or even

```
function WindowExists(const TitleName: string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := Winapi.Windows.FindWindow(nil, PChar(TitleName)) <> 0;
end;
```

Note that it is always pointless to write code like this:

```
A := 0;
A := 1;
```

That is what your code did in essence in the first two lines of the function. It is also idiomatic to use the not equal operator `<>` instead of negating the equal operator.

Comment: Could you tell me if that window exists how to send it a restore message?

Comment: That's a different question

Comment: Ok I posted an other question, Thanks!!!     [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34004258/sending-a-restore-message-from-fm-to-another-application