# Sending a restore message from FM to another Application

Tags: delphi, findwindow

I was provided some great help in finding if a window existed in FM.

Now I need to know how to restore that window , if it does exists.

thanks

```
 function WindowExists(const TitleName: string): Boolean;
begin
   Result := Winapi.Windows.FindWindow(nil, PChar(TitleName)) <> 0;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `ShowWindow` passing the window handle and the `SW_RESTORE` flag.